# How do I plot a probability heatmap with ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, tidyverse

Say I have a bunch of data with x and y coordinates and `TRUE`/`FALSE` for each row:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(666) #666 for the devil
x <- rnorm(1000, 50, 10)
y <- sample(1:100, 1000, replace = T)
result <- sample(c(T, F), 1000, prob = c(1, 9),replace = T)
data <- tibble(x, y, result)
```

Now, I want to make a plot that shows the likelihood of an area being `TRUE` based on that data. I could group the data into little squares(or whatever) and calculate the `TRUE` percentage and then plot that but what I wonder if there is something in `ggplot2` that will do that for me automatically.

Comment: Huh, off-topic? The specific reason given is not accurate. I did not ask "why isn't this code working?" I asked "I don't know how to do X, how do I do X?" which is different and from my understanding the whole point of this website, no?!

Comment: Hi, @rui-barradas, could you clarify how the aforementioned rule was broken? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, z = as.numeric(result))) +
    stat_summary_2d(bins = 20, color = "grey", fun = mean) +        
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not completely in `ggplot2` but the following produces what I think you are asking for

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
set.seed(666) #666 for the devil

data.frame(x = rnorm(1000, 50, 10), 
           y = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = T), 
           result = sample(c(T, F), 1000, prob = c(1, 9), replace = T)) %>% 
  do(augment(glm(result ~ x * y, data = ., family = "binomial"), type.predict = "response")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = .fitted)) + 
  geom_point()
```

or `geom_hex` instead of `geom_point` looks interesting

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an other solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Preparing data
set.seed(666) #666 for the devil
data <- tibble(x = rnorm(1000, 50, 10),
               y = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = T),
               result = sample(c(T, F), 1000, 
                               prob = c(1, 9), replace = T)) %>%
filter(result == TRUE)

#Plotting with ggplot
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
geom_bin2d()
```

[image: Result geom_bin2d]